# how to check if time is within a specific range in swift

Tags: swift, time

Hi I am trying to check if the current time is within a time range, say 8:00 - 16:30. My code below shows that I can obtain the current time as a string, but I am unsure how I can use this value to check if it is inside the time range specified above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
var dateInFormat:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)
println(dateInFormat) // 23:54
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Personally, I don't like working with strings if I can avoid it. I'd rather deal with date components.

Below is code that creates dates for 8:00 and 16:30, and then compares the dates to see if the current date/time falls in that range.

It's longer than other people's code, but I think it's worth learning how to do calculations with dates using a Calendar:

### EDIT #3:

This answer is from a long time ago. I'll leave the old answer below, but here is the current solution:

@CodenameDuchess' answer uses a system function, `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`

Using that function, the code can be simplified to this:

```
import UIKit

// The function `Calendar.date(bySettingHour:minute:second)` lets you 
// create date objects for a given time in the same day of given date
// For example, 8:00 today

let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let eight_today = calendar.date(
  bySettingHour: 8,
  minute: 0,
  second: 0,
  of: now)!

let four_thirty_today = calendar.date(
  bySettingHour: 16,
  minute: 30,
  second: 0,
  of: now)!

// In recent versions of Swift Date objectst are comparable, so you can 
// do greater than, less than, or equal to comparisons on dates without
// needing a date extension

if now >= eight_today &&
  now <= four_thirty_today
{
  print("The time is between 8:00 and 16:30")
}
```

The old (Swift 2) answer follows, for historical completeness:

This code uses a Calendar object to get the day/month/year of the current date, and adds the desired hour/minute components, and then generates a date for those components.

```
import UIKit
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//NSDate extensions.
extension NSDate
{
  /**
  This adds a new method dateAt to NSDate.

  It returns a new date at the specified hours and minutes of the receiver

  :param: hours: The hours value
  :param: minutes: The new minutes

  :returns: a new NSDate with the same year/month/day as the receiver, but with the specified hours/minutes values
  */
  func dateAt(#hours: Int, minutes: Int) -> NSDate
  {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

    //get the month/day/year componentsfor today's date.

    println("Now = \(self)")

    let date_components = calendar.components(
      NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth |
        NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,
      fromDate: self)

    //Create an NSDate for 8:00 AM today.
    date_components.hour = hours
    date_components.minute = minutes
    date_components.second = 0

    let newDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(date_components)!
        return newDate
  }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//Tell the system that NSDates can be compared with ==, >, >=, <, and <= operators
extension NSDate: Equatable {}
extension NSDate: Comparable {}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
//Define the global operators for the 
//Equatable and Comparable protocols for comparing NSDates

public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 == rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 < rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}
public func >(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 > rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}
public func <=(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 <= rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}
public func >=(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.timeIntervalSince1970 >= rhs.timeIntervalSince1970
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------

let now = NSDate()
let eight_today = now.dateAt(hours: 8, minutes: 0)
let four_thirty_today = now.dateAt(hours:16, minutes: 30)

if now >= eight_today &&
  now <= four_thirty_today
{
  println("The time is between 8:00 and 16:30")
}
```

### EDIT:

The code in this answer has changed a LOT for Swift 3.

Instead of using `NSDate`, it makes more sense to us the native `Date` object, and `Date` objects are `Equatable` and `Comparable` "out of the box".

Thus we can get rid of the `Equatable` and `Comparable` extensions and the definitions for the `<`, `>` and `=` operators.

Then we need to do a fair amount of tweaking of the syntax in the `dateAt` function to follow Swift 3 syntax. The new extension looks like this in Swift 3:

### Swift 3 version:

```
import Foundation

extension Date
{

  func dateAt(hours: Int, minutes: Int) -> Date
  {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!

    //get the month/day/year componentsfor today's date.


    var date_components = calendar.components(
      [NSCalendar.Unit.year,
       NSCalendar.Unit.month,
       NSCalendar.Unit.day],
      from: self)

    //Create an NSDate for the specified time today.
    date_components.hour = hours
    date_components.minute = minutes
    date_components.second = 0

    let newDate = calendar.date(from: date_components)!
    return newDate
  }
}


let now = Date()
let eight_today = now.dateAt(hours: 8, minutes: 0)
let four_thirty_today = now.dateAt(hours: 16, minutes: 30)

if now >= eight_today &&
  now <= four_thirty_today
{
  print("The time is between 8:00 and 16:30")
}
```

Comment: The code above seems to work, however the current time is taken as GMT.  Is there a way to create an NSDate object that uses the local time zone on the phone, or one specified, such as Australian Eastern Time, which is UTC/GMT + 10.

Comment: NSDates do not use any time zone. They are always stored internally in GMT/UTC. It's only when you display them that you see them in a particular time zone. The easiest way to display a date in a specific time zone is to use a date formatter. (Although it looks like the `println("\(someDate)")` syntax displays in the default locale on the device.

Comment: Yes but if doing some sort of calculation such as compare, then wouldn't my results be incorrect since I haven't accounted for the offset? Alternatively I think I can just convert my 8:00 and 16:30 to GMT and that should work.

Comment: No. NSDates describe a moment in time anywhere on the planet. They use UTC internally. If 2 NSDates are identical, they describe the same instant in time all over, regardless of time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Duncan, I tested it, and it works like you said. Cheers.

Comment: This was a really exceptional answer @DuncanC  thanks so much

Comment: @PSUSabes, no problem Glad to help. Now who gave the drive-by down vote? Man that's infuriating. If you feel my answer was incomplete or somehow gave bad info, then please, by all means down-vote and tell me what's wrong with it, but don't down vote with no explanation!

Comment: great answer, especially the update #2 for Swift 3. thanks for being so clear & thorough :-)

Comment: How can i check if my timestamp is Less than 2:00 am the next day ?

Comment: Don't post a new question in the comments for an answer to a different question. Post a new question, and link to this answer.

Comment: @MahmoudZinji if you post your question as a new comment and tag me I'll answer you.

Comment: I created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584666/how-would-i-get-the-date-of-200-am-the-next-day-in-swift/73584697?noredirect=1#comment129942709_73584697) and answered it.

Comment: Top answer! This makes it so simple to calculate if the current time is between given times.

Answer (score 18):

In Swift 3.0 you can use the new Date value type and compare directly with ==,>,< etc

```
let now = NSDate()
let nowDateValue = now as Date
let todayAtSevenAM = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 7, minute: 0, second: 0, of: nowDateValue, options: [])
let todayAtTenPM = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 22, minute: 0, second: 0, of: nowDateValue, options: [])

if nowDateValue >= todayAtSevenAM! &&
   nowDateValue <= todayAtTenPM!
{
    // date is in range
}
```

Very handy indeed.

Comment: depreciated...?

Comment: Duchess, good answer, using `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:)`. That's a newer `Calendar` function that seem to have missed. It obviates the need for my `Date` extension.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:options:)` is an `NSCalendar` function, and the equivalent Swift 3 `Calendar` function is `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`

Comment: Thanks it worked for me in swift 3 I m using this code:
let todayAtEightAM = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hourStart, minute: minStart, second: 00, of: nowDateValue)
        let todayAtSevenThirtyPM = calendar.date(bySettingHour: hourEnd, minute: minEnd, second: 00, of: nowDateValue)

Answer (score 7):

You can get year, month, and day from today's date, append those to those date time strings to build new `Date` objects. Then `compare` the `todaysDate` to those two resulting `Date` objects:

```
let todaysDate  = Date()
let startString = "8:00"
let endString   = "16:30"

// convert strings to `Date` objects

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let startTime = formatter.date(from: startString)
let endTime = formatter.date(from: endString)

// extract hour and minute from those `Date` objects

let calendar = Calendar.current

var startComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startTime!)
var endComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: endTime!)

// extract day, month, and year from `todaysDate`

let nowComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year], from: todaysDate)

// adjust the components to use the same date

startComponents.year  = nowComponents.year
startComponents.month = nowComponents.month
startComponents.day   = nowComponents.day

endComponents.year  = nowComponents.year
endComponents.month = nowComponents.month
endComponents.day   = nowComponents.day

// combine hour/min from date strings with day/month/year of `todaysDate`

guard
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: startComponents),
    let endDate = calendar.date(from: endComponents)
else {
    print("unable to create dates")
    return
}

// now we can see if today's date is inbetween these two resulting `NSDate` objects

let isInRange = todaysDate > startDate && todaysDate < endDate
```

See [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29653906/2) for Swift 2 answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Following soltion get current time from the system  and then check it exist that range or not .
In my case time range is 8:00 am to 5:00 pm 
 The Solution Valid for Swift 4.2

```
 func CheckTime()->Bool{
    var timeExist:Bool
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startTimeComponent = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour:8)
    let endTimeComponent   = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: 17, minute: 00)

    let now = Date()
    let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
    let startTime    = calendar.date(byAdding: startTimeComponent, to: startOfToday)!
    let endTime      = calendar.date(byAdding: endTimeComponent, to: startOfToday)!

    if startTime <= now && now <= endTime {
        print("between 8 AM and 5:30 PM")
        timeExist = true
    } else {
        print("not between 8 AM and 5:30 PM")
        timeExist = false
    }
    return timeExist
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code I use in one of my current projects. Just set start time as 8:00, end time as 16:30, and timeStamp as current time.

```
func isTimeStampCurrent(timeStamp:NSDate, startTime:NSDate, endTime:NSDate)->Bool{
    timeStamp.earlierDate(endTime) == timeStamp && timeStamp.laterDate(startTime) == timeStamp
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their feedback. I am going through now, and seeing which one is easiest to implement.

Answer (score 3):

also, the solution below looks short if i want to see if the time is in a specific range during day

```
var greeting = String()
let date     = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour     = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
//let minutes  = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let morning = 3; let afternoon=12; let evening=16; let night=22;

print("Hour: \(hour)")
if morning < hour, hour < afternoon {
    greeting = "Good Morning!"
}else if afternoon < hour, hour < evening{
    greeting = "Good Afternoon!"
}else if evening < hour, hour < night{
    greeting = "Good Evening!"
}else{
    greeting = "Good Night"
}
print(greeting)
```

i guess you could modify it, to check for example, if the months are in certain ranges too, e.g:

```
sum = "Jan"
win = "March"
Spr = "May"
Aut = "Sept"
```

and continue from there...

Comment: This one is best and easy!

Answer (score 2):

You could make `NSDate` conform to the `Comparable` protocol to be able to use the `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=`, `>` and `<` operators. For example:

```
extension NSDate : Comparable {}

//  To conform to Comparable, NSDate must also conform to Equatable.
//  Hence the == operator.
public func == (lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

public func > (lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedDescending
}

public func < (lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

public func <= (lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return  lhs == rhs || lhs < rhs
}

public func >= (lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs || lhs > rhs
}
```

To use this to check a date was within two dates you could use:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let olderDate   = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -100)
let newerDate   = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 100)

olderDate < currentDate && currentDate < newerDate // Returns true
```

Here are a few more examples of how to use the operators with `NSDate`:

```
olderDate < newerDate  // True
olderDate > newerDate  // False
olderDate != newerDate // True
olderDate == newerDate // False
```

Comment: I had that in my answer as well, but Swift 3 made Date objects compatible and equatable, so this extension is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

check this link

to know that how to use dateformator in swift please check the link below

[image]

https://nsscreencast.com/episodes/367-dates-and-times

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the [essential parts of the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Date { 
    /// time returns a double for which the integer represents the hours from 1 to 24 and the decimal value represents the minutes.  
    var time: Double {
        Double(Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self)) + Double(Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)) / 100
    }
}

// usage 
print(9.30...16.30 ~= Date().time ? "If you're on the East Coast, It is during market hours" : "its after hours")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `compare` method from `NSDate`: it will return an `NSComparisonResult` (`OrderedSame`, `OrderedAscending` or `OrderedDescending`) that you can check against your start and end dates:

```
let dateMaker = NSDateFormatter()
dateMaker.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
let start = dateMaker.dateFromString("2015/04/15 08:00:00")!
let end = dateMaker.dateFromString("2015/04/15 16:30:00")!

func isBetweenMyTwoDates(date: NSDate) -> Bool {
    if start.compare(date) == .OrderedAscending && end.compare(date) == .OrderedDescending {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

println(isBetweenMyTwoDates(dateMaker.dateFromString("2015/04/15 12:42:00")!)) // prints true
println(isBetweenMyTwoDates(dateMaker.dateFromString("2015/04/15 17:00:00")!)) // prints false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare date like this.

```
extension NSDate {

func isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isGreater = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
        isGreater = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isGreater
}

func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isLess = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
        isLess = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isLess
}

func equalToDate(dateToCompare: NSDate) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isEqualTo = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
        isEqualTo = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isEqualTo
}

func addDays(daysToAdd: Int) -> NSDate {
    let secondsInDays: NSTimeInterval = Double(daysToAdd) * 60 * 60 * 24
    let dateWithDaysAdded: NSDate = self.dateByAddingTimeInterval(secondsInDays)

    //Return Result
    return dateWithDaysAdded
}

func addHours(hoursToAdd: Int) -> NSDate {
    let secondsInHours: NSTimeInterval = Double(hoursToAdd) * 60 * 60
    let dateWithHoursAdded: NSDate = self.dateByAddingTimeInterval(secondsInHours)

    //Return Result
    return dateWithHoursAdded
 }
}
```