# UIDatePicker to call specific image in UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uidatepicker

Why is `"1925-1-23"` and `"1924-2-5"` being excluded when I try to call an image with them in date picker? I am successfully able to call images with  every date in between the two dates above. Why are the dates `"1925-1-23"` and `"1924-2-5"` the only dates not calling images.

```
   import UIKit

   public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedDescending
}

extension NSDate: Comparable { }



class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var displayAnimal: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var dateWheel: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func goButton(sender: UIDatePicker)

    {

        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")        

   {

    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let rabbit1A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1924-2-5")
    let rabbit2A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1925-1-23")

    if(dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit1A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending && 
 dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending)
    {
    // set the image of UIImageView
    displayAnimal.image = UIImage(named: "rabbit")
    }
```

Comment: I thought this is quite straightforward to compare a date, then set image of `UIImageView`... isn't it ? See the answer below

Comment: @Raptor I have made the changes suggested at this point I am getting a message stating cannot find initalizer.. What do you think?  I made it some what more clear in my original question above. thanks

Comment: I don't see an initializer in the docs that takes a parameter dateString. There is this convenience initializer: `convenience init?(string description: String)`. You'd call that one like this: `var dateA = NSDate(string: "2014-02-02 00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: It's better if you add an **EDIT** tag at the bottom of your question and post new code there. When you make repeated wholesale changes to your post it makes it all but impossible to follow the thread of the discussion and learn from it, or tell if you are still asking for help.

Comment: If your code isn't behaving as expected then you should set breakpoints and step through it to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `IBOutlet`:

```
@IBAction func selectDateButton(sender : UIDatePicker) {
  // set the date criteria here
  if(sender.date.compare(dateA) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending && sender.date.compare(dateB) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) {
     // set the image of UIImageView
     displayAnimal.image = UIImage(named: "rabbit")
  }
}
```

where `dateA` and `dateB` are the date (in form of `NSDate`) that falls into the criteria of displaying rabbit image.

Comment: if I guessed correctly, you're working on Chinese Zodiac. Each Zodiac has a period, for example, from 1985-2-15 to 1986-2-14 is ox. You just have to fit the dates into `dateA` and `dateB`...

Comment: example: `dateA = NSDate(dateString:"2014-06-06")`

Answer (score 0):

A date picker won't talk to an image view. A date picker is a UIControl.

The logic to do what you want belongs in your view controller.

You would set up an IBOutlet to your date picker.
You'd add an OK button to your view controller in IB that linked to an IBAction method.

In that IBAction method you would look at the date property of the picker (using the picker's outlet.) If the date matches one of your magic dates, you'd have code that would load one of your images into an image view that was linked to another IBOutlet in your view controller.

Break it down into baby steps. Hook up the outlets and actions. At first just put a `println("In button action")` in your IBAction method. Next, fetch the date from the picker and log that in your IBAction.

Next, figure out how to write a switch statement that matches your different dates and prints statements when you match your different dates. That will require a detour into the docs to read about Swift's very powerful switch statement.

Next figure out how to load your different images from your array of names and install them into an image view on your view controller when you click a button. (First set up an Int instance variable `imageIndex` that starts at 0, and have a button press load an image name from you array of image names, increment the index for next time, and then installs the loaded image into your image view.

Finally, adjust your switch statement so your various magic dates load the desired image into your image view.

Comment: Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments Got it down to one error. what does it mean ? ( this is based on Raptors code in the answer above)

Comment: You can't use == to compare dates unless you add an extension to the NSDate class. Other ways to compare dates are to use the compare method. `if date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderSame`. See my reply in [**this thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652771/how-to-check-if-time-is-within-a-specific-range-in-swift/29654806#29654806) for an extension to NSDate that does allow you to use == (and <, >, <=, and >=). It's a handy thing to include in any project that uses dates.

Comment: I made the changes could you take a look at it now? ( I used the extension suggested now its an initializer issue.