# Swift: How to display one of the two Images depending of the current time of the day

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have images named open and close, which are displayed according to the store timings. According to Indian Standard time the store timings are 11Am to 11PM, during this time I want to display the open image and closed image in the remaining time. Can someone help me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652771/how-to-check-if-time-is-within-a-specific-range-in-swift check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, get current time in hours (it is 24 hour format)

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Hour], fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
```

Then check for time

```
if hour >= 11 && hour <= 22 {
    // show open image
}
else {
    // show close image
}
```

Comment: if it is <=23 means, it will open till 23:59:59

Answer (score 0):

```
var component: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: currentDate)
var strStoreStatus: String = (component.hour() >= 11 && component.hour() <= 22) ? "OPEN" : "CLOSE"
```

Comment: "timings": [
        [
          "11:30 AM",
          "11:30 PM"
        ]
      ],

I have a JSON data as mentioned above. Can you help on how can I display according to this. I know how to download the data, I need help after that. Like, how do it put the timings in JSON in the component.hour() after downloading.

Comment: var component: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: currentDate)

Comment: Now you will also get minute, rest you have to do yourself