# i want to show the avalible times as bold and unavaliable times(strike) in label with corresponding to api data

Tags: ios, swift, api, if-statement, conditional-statements

[image]

for api data for day(different timings for all days & sunday closed) and date, get the entering time and leaving time, from that change the label as bold in avialiable time and strike on unaavaliable times.

before entering time all times are unavaliable and after leaving all times are unavaliable and also lunch time unavaliable

how to write the condition from api data to the label change(to bold/ strike)

**API response:**

```
 Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600003873050>(
 {
  day = Saturday;
  dArray = "<null>";
  enteringTime = "09.00 am";
  entryTime = "<null>";
  exitTime = "<null>";
  id = 13;
  leavingTime = "06.00 pm";
  lunchtimeFrom = "13:00";
  lunchtimeTo = "14:00";
 }
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "08:05 AM") 

attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length)) 

time805Lbl.attributedText = attributeString
```

Comment: Don't be hesitate and attached your code what you have done so far. So that We can check your code.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652771/how-to-check-if-time-is-within-a-specific-range-in-swift

Comment: only give strike manually with respect to api timings

Comment: let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "08:05 AM")
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        time805Lbl.attributedText = attributeString

Comment: @SruthiCSankar what value you are checking - `enteringTime ` or `leavingTime` or both?

Comment: both enteringTime = "09.00 am";leavingTime = "06.00 pm";
  lunchtimeFrom = "13:00";
  lunchtimeTo = "14:00";

Comment: in img before entering and after leaving all times are busy and the lunch time also

Comment: @SruthiCSankar so there is no time duration? Only check the whether UILabel text is match with any of these will be strike out? Is it?

Comment: please answer with condition code?

Comment: `lunchtimeFrom` and `lunchtimeTo` value are different. Can you please confirm its type same for all of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191011/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-sruthi-c-sankar).

Comment: no different for different person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Date format in your `viewController` -

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

**Now, add a method to check available time**

```
func checkAvailableTime(currentTime: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: currentTime)

    var time = "\(times["lunchtimeFrom"]!)"
    let lunchStartTime = dateFormatter.date(from: time)

    time = "\(times["lunchtimeTo"]!)"
    let lunchEndTime = dateFormatter.date(from: time)


    let personCheckTime = dateFormatter.date(from: currentTime)


    if  (lunchStartTime!.compare(personCheckTime!) == .orderedAscending) && (lunchEndTime!.compare(personCheckTime!) == .orderedDescending){

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    }

    return attributeString
}
```

**Time to call that method -**

```
time805Lbl.attributedText = checkAvailableTime(currentTime: time805Lbl.text!)
```

Where `times` is your time response.
I hope you get response as below -

```
let times = [
    "day":"Saturday",
    "dArray":"<null>",
    "enteringTime":"09:00 AM",
    "entryTime":"<null>",
    "exitTime":"<null>",
    "id": 13,
    "leavingTime":"06:00 PM",
    "lunchtimeFrom":"1:00 PM",
    "lunchtimeTo":"2:00 PM"
    ] as [String : Any]
```

Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: Is this label change to button possible? and what changes in code??

Comment: @SruthiCSankar you have replace all `UILabel` to `UIButton` and `time805Lbl.attributedText = checkAvailableTime(currentTime: time805Lbl.text!)` to `button.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)`

Comment: Better use `IBOutlet Collection` for all your `buttons`

Comment: error getting... Use of unresolved identifier 'attString'

Comment: @SruthiCSankar `attString` will be your `checkAvailableTime(currentTime: button.title(for: .normal)!)`