# How to structure data inside Core Data for the following scenario

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the a `Person` object store in `Core Data` which contains two attributes:

- name
- payment

Now I decided I want to also store the average of payments for a day/month/year.

How should I store this inside Core Data ? Inside the `Person` object ? Create new objects ?

Comment: Why store the average?  Why not calculate it when required?

Comment: Do not burden your core data stack. Your situation can be handled by creating logic in subClass (NSObject) or in view Controller(not preferred). Create a method that return float from payment attribute after making calculation on it. Use it when required. i.e. -(float) averageMonthlyPayment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to store summary data. You can add convenience methods to your managed object subclass to deliver the desired value. Something along these lines:

```
func averageForPeriod(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> Double {
    guard self.payments != nil else { return 0 }
    let periodPayments = (self.payments as Set<Payment>).filter {
         $0.date >= startDate && $0.date <= endDate
    }
    return periodPayments.valueForKeyPath("@avg.amount").doubleValue
}
```

*NB: for comparing dates like this you need to define your own comparison function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109990/427083), or you can use `NSTimeInterval`.*