# Archive is not success, due to error code -1, Although I can do build and install in my devices with developement profile

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

My Application is coded with swift 3 And core-data as offline information storage.

I'm not able to archive my application due to long list or error like

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Ashwin/Library/Developer
/Xcode/DerivedData/BeerScout-eweygxkfdhbkbkalbiyywrsuievg/Build
/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/BeerScout/IntermediateBuildFilesPath
/BeerScout.build/Release-iphoneos/BeerScout.build/DerivedSources
/CoreDataGenerated/BeerScout/Beer+CoreDataClass.swift'
...
And at last 
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I have checked for

```
#1 Code optimizations
#2 Clean project and derived data
#3 Also checked for code-gen for core data files.
#4 Revoke and recreate new certificates
#5 Cleaning system junks and re-started several times
```

None of above is resolving my issue. Please suggest me what I have visited almost all related links over stack. And googled for same.

Thank you

Comment: Are your files added in Build Phase->Compile sources?

Comment: Every thing is working fine... just not able to do archive to upload at itunesconnect.

Comment: This is frequent error and get resolved automatically whine i continues tried for 30-40 minutes of clean and archive.

Comment: What is your setting on your model entities for Codegen?

Comment: its manual/none now but still same issue.

Comment: Do you tried this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/194256#194313

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had gone with the above link

[Xcode 6.0.1 Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded)

And

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/194256#194313

With manual/none code generation, I got lots of error. Then I add core data and its properties file for all my entity from Menu bar's editor option(by selecting all entities) so it creates all needful swift class at once.

[image]

This supposes to be work as per apple's forum link.