# Is a date in same week, month, year of another date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

What is the best way to know if a date is in the same week (or year or month) as another, preferably with an extension, and **solely using Swift**?

As an example, in Objective-C I have

```
- (BOOL)isSameWeekAs:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDateComponents *otherDay = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self];
    NSDateComponents *today = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
    return ([today weekOfYear]   == [otherDay weekOfYear] &&
            [today year]         == [otherDay year] &&
            [today era]          == [otherDay era]);
}
```

Please don't propose solutions bridging `Date` to `NSDate`

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to convert this code to Swift. Clearly describe what issues you are having.

Comment: Did you read through this entire post? [NSDate Comparison using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26198526/2415822)

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry that question wasn't a problem per say, but having not found a direct answer through a search, I though it was a question worth getting into SO for people in need for the same answer. But yes I was lazy because I didn't came with the answer directly, mea culpa.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use calendar method `isDate(equalTo:granularity:)` to check it as follow:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Date {

    func isEqual(to date: Date, toGranularity component: Calendar.Component, in calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Bool {
        calendar.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: component)
    }

    func isInSameYear(as date: Date) -> Bool { isEqual(to: date, toGranularity: .year) }
    func isInSameMonth(as date: Date) -> Bool { isEqual(to: date, toGranularity: .month) }
    func isInSameWeek(as date: Date) -> Bool { isEqual(to: date, toGranularity: .weekOfYear) }

    func isInSameDay(as date: Date) -> Bool { Calendar.current.isDate(self, inSameDayAs: date) }

    var isInThisYear:  Bool { isInSameYear(as: Date()) }
    var isInThisMonth: Bool { isInSameMonth(as: Date()) }
    var isInThisWeek:  Bool { isInSameWeek(as: Date()) }

    var isInYesterday: Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(self) }
    var isInToday:     Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self) }
    var isInTomorrow:  Bool { Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(self) }

    var isInTheFuture: Bool { self > Date() }
    var isInThePast:   Bool { self < Date() }
}
```

Comment: Let's say we use `Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .day)` and dates are 1 january of 2016 and 2017, does it return false ?

Comment: yes it would be same as isDateInSameDay. See my edit

Comment: Accepting that answer as I think readability > functional, but @Mr.Hedgehog is a very nice answer

Comment: Why  are you passing 'date' as argument ? this can be done like Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .year) and using like dateToBeChecked. isInSameYear() I guess, you are doing reverse (currentDate.isInSameYear(checkingDate))

Answer (score 13):

You can use this extension that is based on the Objective-C code you've provided:

```
extension Date {
    func hasSame(_ components: Calendar.Component..., as date: Date, using calendar: Calendar = .autoupdatingCurrent) -> Bool {
             return components.filter { calendar.component($0, from: date) != calendar.component($0, from: self) }.isEmpty
    }
}
```

The default calendar here is the `autoupdatingCurrent` so if user changes the calendar it will update accordingly. Also it uses variadic parameter components that allows you to specify any number of components without wrapping them into an array.

Example of usage:

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date()
let date3 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 30.0)

print(date1.hasSame(.weekOfYear, .day, .hour, as: date2)) // true
print(date1.hasSame(.weekOfYear, as: date3)) // false
```

EDIT

As @Leo Dabus pointed out we may use set here instead of array/variadic parameters - that way we'll avoid comparing the same components many times if user passes some duplicates to the method:

```
extension Date {
    func hasSame(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, as date: Date, using calendar: Calendar = .autoupdatingCurrent) -> Bool {
             return components.filter { calendar.component($0, from: date) != calendar.component($0, from: self) }.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would we use set here? I cannot see any point except for removing duplicates

Comment: Ok i see, at first I was not convinced if we should prevent such a misusage but that's like no cost at all (except for the variadic syntax which is more of a personal preference). Thanks for your comment I'll update my answer