# Make sure returned dates are within seven days of current date

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

Currently I am using these group of functions to filter date objects that are used inside my app.

```
func isInSameWeek(date: Date) -> Bool {
    return Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .weekOfYear)
}
func isInSameMonth(date: Date) -> Bool {
    return Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .month)
}
func isInSameYear(date: Date) -> Bool {
    return Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .year)
}
func isInSameDay(date: Date) -> Bool {
    return Calendar.current.isDate(self, equalTo: date, toGranularity: .day)
}
var isInThisWeek: Bool {
    return isInSameWeek(date: Date())
}
var isInToday: Bool {
    return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self)
}
var isInTheFuture: Bool {
    return Date() < self
}
var isInThePast: Bool {
    return self < Date()
}
```

They are working fine but the only issue is that I want to return date objects that are within 7 days of the current day. So if a date object occurs on the Feb 11th than it should be returned as well. Currently what I have won't return anything unless it is literally in the same calendar week.

Comment: [Check if date falls between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859569/check-if-date-falls-between-2-dates) - just create two dates +/- 7 days from the current date and compare

Comment: So basically what you wanted to say is that you copy+pasted the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664156/1974224, and you need to add new functions but you don't know how? You should at least give attribution to the person you took the code from.

Comment: If the current instant is 2019-02-01-12:00:00, would you consider 2019-02-08-14:00:00 to be “within 7 days”? There is a 7 day and 2 hour difference between those two instants.

Comment: @robmayoff technically not but I just want the day as a whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution getting the end date with the `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:)` API of `Calendar`

```
extension Date {
    func isInSevenDays() -> Bool {
        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let weekday = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday], from: now)
        let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
        let nextWeekday = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: weekday, matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
        let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: nextWeekday)!
        return self >= startDate && self < endDate
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah for example if today is Wednesday I want to show dates up until the next Wednesday

Comment: *until the next Wednesday* is still ambiguous. Please specify the exact date range (like in my answer) for today, Tuesday, noon (12:00)

Comment: sorry for example 

Tuesday, Feb 5th to Tuesday, Feb 12th

Comment: * sigh * please add the times, too.

Comment: sorry for example Tuesday, Feb 5th (00:00) to Tuesday, Feb 12th (23:59)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to consider just the calendar date portion of each `Date`, and ignore the time of day. Thus you would consider 2019-02-01-12:00:00 to be within 7 days of 2019-02-08-14:00:00, even though there are 7 days and 2 hours between those two instants, which is more than 7 days exactly.

You can use two `Calendar` methods to compute the difference in calendar days between two `Date`s, ignoring time of day. First, get the year, month, and day components of each `Date`, discarding the time of day parts:

```
    let aymd = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: a)
    let bymd = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: b)
```

Then ask the `Calendar` for the difference in days between the two `DateComponents`:

```
    let diff = dateComponents([.day], from: aymd, to: bymd).day!
```

This `diff` is the signed number of days between the two input dates. It is positive if `b` is after `a`, and negative if `b` precedes `a`.

I would wrap this up in an extension on `Calendar` like this:

```
extension Calendar {

    func roundedDays(from a: Date, to b: Date) -> Int {
        let aymd = dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: a)
        let bymd = dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: b)
        let diff = dateComponents([.day], from: aymd, to: bymd).day!
        return diff
    }

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

if abs(calendar.roundedDays(from: Date(), to: targetDate)) <= 7 {
    print("\(targetDate) is within 7 days of now")
}
```