# Date to String [format string] String to Date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, date-formatting

I've racked my brain over this issue all day and can't seem to get a solution.  I have a fitness program that queries the Health Data Store.  In the predicateForSamples(withStart: myStartDate, end: myEndDate) I am finding that getting a date from a datePicker sends a moment in time and therefore my query does not return the results for the entire day as I'd like.  So, I figured if I take that datePicker date and convert it to a starting and ending format my issue would be solved.  However, using the let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) is returning the correct date but the time returns as 04:00:00 +0000 for both functions.

If anybody has a suggestion, please feel free to lend a helping hand.  Thank you so very much!

```
func convertStartDate(StartDate: Date) -> Date {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd '00':'00':'01' +0000"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: StartDate)
    print("convertingStartDate() - \(dateString)")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    print(date as Any)

    return date!
}

func convertEndDate(EndDate: Date) -> Date {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd '23':'59':'59' +0000"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: EndDate)
    print("convertingEndDate() - \(dateString)")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    return date!
}
```

Comment: Here is the output:  2020-04-09 04:00:00 +0000

Comment: Why there are numbers in your date format pattern ??

Comment: I wanted a specific time to capture all the data in Health Kit.  So, I changed it to just after and just before midnight.

Comment: The date is correct if your time zone is -04:00. `print` shows dates always in UTC (+0000). The time format `'00':'00':'01'` is syntactic sugar.

Comment: You should keep your date unchanged and if you would like to know if a date is in  same day as another you can use Calendar method isDate inSameDayAs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292885-isdate and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664156/2303865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue

```
func convertStartDate(StartDate: Date) -> Date {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd '00':'00':'01' +0000"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: StartDate)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    print(date as Any)

    return date!
}

func convertEndDate(EndDate: Date) -> Date {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd '23':'59':'59' +0000"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: EndDate)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    return date!
}
```

Comment: The output came back as 2020-04-09 04:00:01 +0000 for convertStartDate when expecting 2020-04-09 00:00:01 +0000.  The same issue with the convertEndDate.  Any ideas of what is happening?  Thank you!

Comment: it is a timezone issue try setting dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

Comment: Sorry.  It's still returning the wrong timezone.  I truly appreciate the help you are providing.

Comment: You should always set your locale to `en_US_POSIX` before setting the dateFormat when using fixed date formats otherwise your dateFormat will reflect the user device locale and settings

Comment: Yes, I mixed locale with timezone line of code, And adding locale and time zone is a good practice and i recommend also having a look at https://williamboles.me/sneaky-date-formatters-exposing-more-than-you-think/

Comment: Here's what I just discovered.  Health Kit must save it's data in UTC time because once I adjusted the time as recommended, the results of my query was wrong.  When I changed it back to UTC, it gave the correct information.  I appreciate all the assistance with this.  I got the result I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above, this is actually fixed by setting `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`, as the seconds from GMT is your issue.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much for popping in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks @Skyler Tanner