# How to check if date is at least previous day?

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, timezone

Hi everyone I'm trying to get a positive answer when comparing a date **earlier** than `today`

To do this I am using a `Date` **extension** with this boolean

```
extension Date {   
    var isPreviousDate: Bool {
        return self.timeIntervalSinceNow.sign == .minus 
    }
}
```

Here is my problem .. when I print the date to compare it tells me that today's date is earlier and I don't understand why

Since I'm having problems I tried to create a current date and compare it with today's date the answer is that today's date is earlier than today ... this is weird because it shouldn't tell me it's older

This is how I create the `date` to compare

```
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.current.identifier)
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone

    guard let selectedDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: Date().currentYear, month: Date().currentMonth, day: Date().currentDate)) else { return }

    print("isPrevious Date :",selectedDate.isPreviousDate)

    print(selectedDate)
```

am I doing something wrong?

this is what I read in the console when I print the created date to compare

```
isPrevious Date: true
2021-02-11 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve since you are talking about “today” but your code is using a time stamp. So is this a date comparison like “earlier than today” or is it a time comparison like “before right now/current time”?

Comment: No as I said in the question I need to compare a specific date with the current date and know if the specific date is earlier than the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeIntervalSinceNow` is a `FloatingPoint` value with a very high precision, that represents seconds passed since the `Date`.

---

To check if current date is at least on a previous day, you could do something like this:

```
extension Date {
    var isAtLeastPreviousDay: Bool {
        return isPast && !isToday
    }

    private var isPast: Bool {
        return self < Date()
    }

    private var isToday: Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion .. Apparently I was able to solve it by setting the boolean this way `self < Date() && !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(self)`

Comment: @kAiN your issue was your calendar timezone set to UTC

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is that you are using a custom calendar using UTC timezone. You should use the current calendar with the current timezone. Note that you can use Calendar method startOfDay to get the start of day of a specific date:

```
extension Date {
    var isPreviousDate: Bool {
        timeIntervalSinceNow.sign == .minus
    }
    var startOfDay: Date {
        Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let now = Date()
let startOfDay = now.startOfDay
print("isPrevious Date:", startOfDay.isPreviousDate) // true
```

---

If you would like to check if a date is in yesterday all you need is to use calendar method isDateInYesterday:

```
extension Date {
    var isDateInYesterday: Bool {
        Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(self)
    }
}
```

---

```
Date().isDateInYesterday                                 // false
Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -3600*24).isDateInYesterday  // true
```

Comment: Not every day has 24 hours, so hardcoded values, such as -3600*24 do not create accurate date representation. To avoid inaccuracies every date calculation should be done using Calendar. Asker wanted to know if previous date is AT LEAST yesterday, and not just yesterday.

Comment: That’s obvious. It is a test.

Comment: His extension is fine. A date in the same day might be already in the past

Comment: @TomasJablonskis https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664156/2303865

Comment: Yeah, I know all of this. Just that asker wanted to know if the date is `<= yesterday` and not  just `== yesterday`

Comment: That’s easy he can simply compare if the date is less than startOfDay of today

Comment: I posted the answer only to warn OP about changing the calendar timezone

Comment: Okay, thats fair.