# Check whether two Dates are equal to minute precision

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nscalendar

I want to check whether two dates are equal, where equal means they have the same value to the minute. I don't want to compare the seconds value.

Ex:

```
// should be equal
11/12/17 11:19:29
11/12/17 11:19:03

// not equal
11/12/17 11:19:59
11/12/17 11:20:00
```

One way I'm thinking of doing it is getting the time components and going through each one. But I'm wondering if there's a faster or cleaner way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39868949/1187415

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Calendar` class provides the `compare(_:to:toGranularity:)` method for this:

```
let result = Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .minute)
```

`result` will indicate whether date1 is >, =, or < than date2.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

You can return a boolean value:

```
let dateCompare = Calendar.current.isDate(date1, equalTo: date2, toGranularity: .minute)

if dateCompare == false {
   // Different date, hour and minute
} else {
   // Same date, hour and minute
}
```