# How to filter a Struct array by Date?

Tags: swift, struct, nsdate, foundation

I have a struct such as :

```
struct AdData {
    var AdRequest = Int?()
    var Date = NSDate?() // eg: 2015-11-01 04:00:00 +0000
}
```

And an array of `AdData`:

```
var RawDataFromDb = [AdData]()
```

I want to find the all the items in `RawDataFromDb` where `Date` matches today's date. I figured I somehow have to remove the time component of the `AdData` `Date` component to compare only the date, but I'm struggling to find an elegant solution.

So far I tried this without success :

```
public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

extension NSDate: Comparable { }


let TodayDate = NSDate()
let TodayRows = RawDataFromDb.filter{($0.Date == TodayDate}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Explain what you think "where Date matches today's date" means. Do you mean that its day, irrespective of time, should be same as today's day, irrespective of time?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it ! Sorry I wasn't very clear

Comment: I am pretty sure that you'll find a solution in the answers to the referenced thread, e.g. using `isDateInToday` from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538987/1187415. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the link. Although it does give some useful information, I suggest we leave this thread open as it relates specifically to Structs and the answers given here differ significantly from the ones in the post you have linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Martin R's comment and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25538987/1187415) you can just use isDateInToday! Which is very simple

You could try something like this:

```
let gregorianCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

let TodayRows = RawDataFromDb.filter{
    return self.gregorianCalendar.isDateInToday($0.Date)
}
```

As for the equals comparable I like to use:

```
extension NSDate: Comparable { }

public func ==(leftDate: NSDate, rightDate: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return leftDate.isEqualToDate(rightDate)
}
```

If you use this, instead of `isDateInToday` you would need to set `Today`'s and `struct.Date`'s hours to 12 (in order to compare dates that land on the first day of daylights savings) and minutes/seconds to zero. Since the hours,minutes, and seconds do effect the comparison.

So for example:

```
let gregorianCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let today: NSDate = gregorianCalendar.dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())!

let TodayRows = RawDataFromDb.filter{
    let structDate = self.gregorianCalendar.dateBySettingHour(12, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())!
    return structDate == self.today
}
```

Comment: You should use 12pm instead of 12am for this type of comparison since not everyday starts at 12am

Comment: Could you explain further? :) Thanks!

Comment: Daylight savings time

Comment: So what you are saying is that the gregorian calendar is no good for daylights savings?

Comment: Nothing to do with the calendar that has its own methods for comparing dates isDateInToday or isDate inSameDayAs

Comment: Ok. Could you be more direct please on what you mean by using 12pm!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94241/discussion-between-boidkan-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Everyday has 12pm but not everyday has 12am

Comment: Oh right. The wheels slowly turned haha ;) So instead of setting hours to zero set them to 12. Obrigado

Comment: After thinking about this longer I have a few questions. First of all doesn't the switch over happen at 2am U.S and 1am EU. Secondly, how would this effect two dates that you set the hours, minutes, and seconds to zero? Unless NSDate does not allow you to set the hour for the date to zero you should be fine when comparing? Also I though NSDate didn't care about timezones and such.

Comment: @boidjan 0 hour of the day can be 1am

Comment: Right but the switch doesnt happen until 2am. This is what I got when playing with 2015-11-01 and setting the hour to 0, 1, and 2:

`2015-11-01 05:00:00 +0000`
`2015-11-01 06:00:00 +0000`
`2015-11-01 08:00:00 +0000`

Chat? So we don't spam here? :)

Comment: See page 37 http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/227xax5xif2s7s531dsmfs1afo2/227/227.pdf

Comment: Thanks, found the video and watching now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most simply, for just today:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()

let targetData = rawData.filter({
  $0.date != nil && calendar.isDateInToday($0.date!)
})
```

For an arbitrary day:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()

let targetDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 123456789)

let targetData = rawData.filter({
  $0.date != nil && calendar.isDate($0.date!, inSameDayAsDate: targetDate)
})
```