# Get date value from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
var result:[Workout] = []
```

The value in result is following, using `print(result)`:

```
[Workout {
    date = 2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Bbb;
    sets = 2;
    reps = 1;
    kg = 77;
    notes = Bb;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-24 18:41:07 +0000;
    name = bvcj;
    exercise = Barbell Bench Press;
    sets = 1;
    reps = 1;
    kg = 87;
    notes = Kjj;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-22 08:02:23 +0000;
    name = Chest;
    exercise = Barbell Bench Press;
    sets = 3;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 95;
    notes = Ok med spot;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-22 08:02:23 +0000;
    name = Chest;
    exercise = Dips;
    sets = 2;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 40;
    notes = Lett, 1 ektra rep på siste sett;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-22 08:02:23 +0000;
    name = Chest;
    exercise = Incline Barbell Bench Press;
    sets = 2;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 72.5;
    notes = Tungt;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-22 08:02:23 +0000;
    name = Chest;
    exercise = Triceps Pushdown;
    sets = 3;
    reps = 12;
    kg = 14.5;
    notes = Ok;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-19 13:38:35 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Squat;
    sets = 2;
    reps = 2;
    kg = 77.5;
    notes = Lett;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-19 13:38:35 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Leg Press;
    sets = 9;
    reps = 8;
    kg = 100;
    notes = Tungt;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-18 10:54:34 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Barbell Squat;
    sets = 3;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 75;
    notes = Tungt;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-18 10:54:34 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Leg Extension;
    sets = 10;
    reps = 10;
    kg = 32;
    notes = Lett;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-17 21:48:52 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Squat;
    sets = 3;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 60;
    notes = Lett;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-17 21:48:52 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Tåhev;
    sets = 4;
    reps = 12;
    kg = 40;
    notes = Tungt;
}, Workout {
    date = 2019-02-17 21:48:52 +0000;
    name = Legday;
    exercise = Leg Extension;
    sets = 3;
    reps = 6;
    kg = 43.5;
    notes = Lett;
}]
```

I want to get only the date, for each workout. I have tried some different things, and the closest I've got, was using this:

```
var remoteIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
func didSelectDayView(_ dayView: DayView, animationDidFinish: Bool) {

    let row = result[remoteIndexPath.row]

    for i in result.indices { // Prøv dette i stedet for: for i in 0 ..< Results.count {
        print(result[remoteIndexPath.row].date)
    }
}
```

The problem is that it only prints out the first value 13 times:

```
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
Optional(2019-03-06 22:18:41 +0000)
```

Any ideas/tips?

Comment: That's an array, not a dictionary. I added an additional answer that should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = result.filter { compareDate(date1:$0.date, date2:savedDate) }
print(res)
```

Comment: The first example only get the first date, the same as I have in the end of my question. I want to go through the whole dictionary, and get the dates that is equal to another date I have saved. So I only want to pris out those dates that is equal.

Comment: read your saved date and use the above way , btw `result` is an array not dictionary

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad.. Looks like it won't show the data at all, since the stored data is stored like: `2019-02-22 08:02:23 +0000 `, and I am looking for `2019-02-22 00:00:00 +0000 `. Looks like it is because of the hours/seconds. How can I bypass that?

Comment: use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/47275545/5820010 for the day comparison

Comment: Looks like that only return boolean value, not the actual dates I want to get?

Comment: yes , but you will use it inside the filter see edit

Comment: Ah, I didn't put it inside the filter. Thank you so much :) You saved the day!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to iterate over an array of objects and return the date property?

I don't know what your workout object looks like so I made one up

```
class Workout {
    var date = ""
    var name = ""

    init(aDate: String, aName: String) {
        self.date = aDate
        self.name = aName
    }
}

var results:[Workout] = []

let w0 = Workout(aDate: "2019-03-06", aName: "Legday")
let w1 = Workout(aDate: "2019-02-24", aName: "bvjc")
let w2 = Workout(aDate: "2019-02-22", aName: "Chest")

results.append(w0)
results.append(w1)
results.append(w2)

let allDates = results.map{ $0.date } //creates an array of just the dates
print(allDates)
```

and the output is

```
["2019-03-06", "2019-02-24", "2019-02-22"]
```