# Locate my database by date, but it checks both the date and the time

Tags: arrays, swift, date, calendar

This code worked well; I had no issues with it until last week, when I flew to another state and opened my app to find that all of my databases were vanished. I'm not sure why this happened, but when I go home, my app works perfectly again. I figured out what was wrong, and it was a time zone change. Can you teach me how to get the date without using a time? I only care about the year, month, and day, but not the hour, minute, second, or time zone. Where can I get code that disregards the time?

My simplest code below

```
func getJournalData(forDate: Date) -> The_journal_data? {
    let theDateCom = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: forDate)
    let freshDate = Calendar.current.date(from: theDateCom)
    let getRawData = theJournalData.first(where: { $0.date == freshDate })
    
    return getRawData
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing NSDates without time component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577087/comparing-nsdates-without-time-component)

Comment: It does not solve my question. I'm not sure how to use that code with a filter. Because it tells me whether or not the dates are match. That is not what I am referring to. I discuss how to find my database using a date but ignore the time. I need to search a database for a date within an array.

Comment: You just replace `$0.date == freshDate` with `Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, equalTo: freshDate, toGranularity: .day)`. Your question is about comparing dates without time. The linked question tells you how to do that.

Comment: Now I understand. I tested it, and it now works, with the exception that it cannot discover today's database but can get databases from yesterday and the past.

Comment: I just discovered that when I shift time zones to the east, such as from mountain time to east time, it works perfectly, but when I go from mountain time to California time, it is unable to locate my today database. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details about your date usage. Specifically `theJournalData.date` and the value of `forData` being passed into `getJournalData`. But first, try getting rid of the `theDataCom` and `freshDate` lines and pass `forDate` directly into the use of `Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, equalTo: forDate, toGranularity: .day)`.

Comment: Note, from the docs:
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date
   Date is a specific point in time, **independent of** any calendar or **time zone**.
 It is as if, all dates are in UTC, timezone zero.
 Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)